# Make a filter to show report from dbgrid

Tags: delphi

I made a report with FastReport and also have the data in DBGrid. I want to report via DBGrid with a double-click event based on the data that I click. For example, I clicked data with ID 007, it will display the report with the data ID 007,how to make the filter?

Comment: You can use another data set connected to FastReport. In this dataset you can filter the data according selected record in DbGrid.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of explanation let's take a look at the folowing example:

DbGrid is connected to database trough DataSource1 -> `MainQuery:TQuery` where `MainQuery.SQL = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1'`;

To show data of only one record selected in DbGrid, you can do the following:

Place another DataSet in the Form, for example `TQuery` component named "FilterQuery" 
Connect FilterQuery to the same data source as MainQuery and assign `FilterQuery.SQL` property as:

variant 1: prepare for filtering by SQL text

```
'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 0'
```

or variant 2:prepare for filtering by parameter

```
'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = :P'
```

or variant 3: prepare for filtering by "filter" property

```
'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID'
```

Connect FastReport component frxDBDataset1: TfrxDBDataset to FilterQuery.
Prepare your FastReport template as you wish to look like.

Now we are ready to show the record.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //prepare the filter according to the selected record
  try
  //Variant 1:
  FilterQuery.SQL :=  Format('SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = %s',[MainQuery.FieldByName('ID').asString]);

  //Variant 2:
  FilterQuery.ParamByName('P').Value :=  MainQuery.FieldByName('ID').Value;

  //Variant 3 ( not recomended because here all data will be loaded from database):
  FilterQuery.Filter := Format('ID = %s', [MainQuery.FieldByName('ID').asString]);
  FilterQuery.Filtered := true;

  //open query
  FilterQuery.Refresh;
  //prepare report
  frxReport1.LoadFromFile('MyReportTemplateFile.fr3');
  frxReport1.PrepareReport;

  //show report
  frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
  finally
    FilterQuery.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: try
     ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT *from TABLE1 WHERE ID ='+     ADOQuery2.FieldByName('ID').asString;

    ADOQuery1open;
  
    frxReport1.LoadFromFile('REPORT.fr3');
    frxReport1.PrepareReport;
   
     frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
finally
     ADOQuery1.Close;
  end;

Comment: @ThomasBrolin do you know what `Format` does?

Comment: @ThomasBrolin everything is ok. We are all here to learn together. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks 
but I changed a little and it works

try 
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT *from TABLE1 WHERE ID ='+
ADOQuery2.FieldByName('ID').asString;

ADOQuery1.open; frxReport1.LoadFromFile('REPORT.fr3');

frxReport1.PrepareReport; frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport; 
finally 
    ADOQuery1.Close; 
end;

Comment: And where is different from my variant 1?